# join objects with same key within same array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, of following type:

```
[{id:1,in:"01/04/2021 21:14:05",out:"01/04/2021 21:14:05"},{id:2,in:"01/04/2021 19:04:05",out:null},{id:1,in:"01/04/2021 22:14:05",out:null}]
```

I want to join objects within this array with same ids, but with some logic behind.

1. Above, there 2 objects with same id (1), and i'd like to get most recent one, i use date-fns for dates.
2. Third object in array has `out:null`, so i'd like to keep the one which is not null.

Right now i have incomplete code for this, but it is very long, how could i make it smaller?
Also, i have temporary array to keep values, but i end up getting two objects with id of 1 and missing object with id of 2.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-panini-vcv0p?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Is most recent determined by the in time or the out time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reducer to achieve this goal,

```
const arr = [
    { id: 1, in: "01/04/2021 21:14:05", out: null },
    { id: 2, in: "01/04/2021 19:04:05", out: false },
    { id: 1, in: "01/04/2021 22:14:05", out: "01/04/2021 21:14:05" }
  ];

  let ret = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    let index = prev.findIndex(item => item.id === curr.id);
    if(index > -1) {
      if(prev[index].in && curr.in) {
        const mostRecentCheckTime = max([
          new Date(prev[index].in),
          new Date(curr.in)
        ]);

        prev[index] ={
          ...prev[index],
          ...curr,
          in: format(mostRecentCheckTime, "P p")
        };
      }
    } else {
      prev.push(curr);
    }
    return prev;
  }, []);

  console.log(ret);
```

Working code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-flower-qqud8?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: you only handled to "in" but not the "out"